# is_main_site() Always Returns True

Tags: multisite, conditional-content

I am using is_main_site() on WordPress Multisite and when I set a break point and view with the debugger it returns true on the primary site and also on a child site I created. Looking at the code I can't see how it would ever return something other than true for a multisite install if the $site_id and $current_site->blog_id are supposed to be two different ways of accessing the same thing (the ID of the site you are currently on. Am I going crazy? Why does this not seem to work? I am running WordPress 4.0.1.

```
function is_main_site( $site_id = null ) {
    // This is the current network's information; 'site' is old terminology.
    global $current_site;

    if ( ! is_multisite() )
        return true;

    if ( ! $site_id )
        $site_id = get_current_blog_id();

    return (int) $site_id === (int) $current_site->blog_id;
}
```

Comment: Have you turned debugging and PHP error messages on? And in what context (where) have you used it?

Comment: I stated in the post I was viewing it with the debugger. I am calling it from a MU plugin. It always returns true.

Comment: What does "with the debugger" mean? Have you turned PHP errors on? Are you running it with `WP_DEBUG` defined as `true`? And on which hook are you running it? `plugins_loaded` for e.g.?

Comment: I am using WP_DEBUG=true which usually shows any errors but there is no error as I am getting true back. I am questioning whether the is_main_site() method in core is correct. I am not calling it inside of a hook but just straight away as the first thing in a MU plugin.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not calling it inside of a hook but just straight away as the first thing in a MU plugin.

At that point all the info you are requesting won't be available. That's running before any hook and before WP is fully loaded.

Use a hook like `wp_loaded`, `admin_init`, `after_setup_theme` ... whatever serves your purpose best.